# How to get joomla version by http?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla1.5

I have seen screenshots of a solution, there the joomla version is getting detected by only accessing the page via http.
E.g. the solution displayed all 3 digits of a version of joomla.
e.g. 2.5.28, or 1.0.x and so on.

So I am wondering how this can be done?

Comment: Please try asking your question on [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done.Append **"/language/en-GB/en-GB.xml"** with the url of the website, and then the document tree will be displayed.You can see the version in the  tag.
Python code to do the same is:-
[image]

Answer (score -2):

this might help althoug I'm struggling to find an option to detect joomla 3.  Basically you can deduce the version of joomla be accessing some of the standard headings used in accessible files.

https://www.gavick.com/blog/how-to-check-the-version-of-joomla

> /templates/system/css/system.css
>
> Find and open the file in your browser and check for this part:
>   Version of Joomla     Source Code Joomla 1.0.x
>
> The easiest way to determine if a site is using Joomla! or not is to
>   view the source code of the page.
>
> Joomla! 1.0.x sites will have the following: 1      Joomla 1.5
>
> /* OpenID icon style */
>
> and in templates\system\css\template.css file you should find this:
>
> - @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 – 2010 Open Source Matters.
>
> in newer versions of Joomla! this file no longer exists
>
> By default, all Joomla! 1.5.x sites will have the following in the
>   head of their site: 1       Joomla 1.6     * @version $Id:
>   system.css 20196 2011-01-09 02:40:25Z ian $ Joomla 1.7    * @version
>   $Id: system.css 21322 2011-05-11 01:10:29Z dextercowley $ Joomla 2.5
>     * @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 – 2012 Open Source Matters
>
> Another way it’s to compare MooTools (JavaScript Framework) versions
>   using a media/system/js/mootools-more.js file: Joomla 1.5
>     MooTools={version:’1.12′} media\system\js\mootools.js Joomla 1.6
>     MooTools.More={version:”1.3.0.1″ Joomla 1.7
>     MooTools.More={version:”1.3.2.1″ Joomla 2.5.6
>     MooTools.More={version:”1.4.0.1″ Joomla 3.0 alpha 2
>     MooTools.More={version:”1.4.0.1″
>
> Another way to check with Joomla 1.6 or Joomla 1.7.x website is based
>   on it’s to compare date in language file: language/en-GB/en-GB.ini
>   Joomla 1.5.26     # $Id: en-GB.ini 11391 2009-01-04 13:35:50Z ian $
>   Joomla 1.6.0  ; $Id: en-GB.ini 20196 2011-01-09 02:40:25Z ian $ Joomla
>   1.6.5     ; $Id: en-GB.ini 20990 2011-03-18 16:42:30Z infograf768 $ Joomla 1.7.1  ; $Id: en-GB.ini 20990 2011-03-18 16:42:30Z infograf768
>   $ Joomla 1.7.3    ; $Id: en-GB.ini 22183 2011-09-30 09:04:32Z
>   infograf768 $ Joomla 1.7.5    ; $Id: en-GB.ini 22183 2011-09-30
>   09:04:32Z infograf768 $ from Joomla 2.5.0 to Joomla 2.5.4
>
> 2.5.0
>
> you’ll will see in language/en-GB/en-GB.xml file. Joomla 2.5.5 Joomla
>   2.5.6
>
> 2.5.5
>
> you’ll will see in language/en-GB/en-GB.xml file.